# Angular UI Router: read child scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent view with a button in it.

**Parent**

`controller: 'ControllerA'`

`Template: 'partials/viewA.html'`

**Child**

`controller: 'ControllerB'`

`Template: 'partials/viewB.html'`

clicking a button in `viewB` sets a value in `ControllerB`

Is it possible to read that value from `viewA` without doing an emit or broadcast?

I basically want `viewA` (parent view) button disabled until the button in `viewB` is clicked.

**EDIT**

essentially it'd be nice to just do:

`<button ng-disabled="ControllerB.someValue">Parent Button</button>`

Comment: not sure what pub/sub is

Comment: why not use a service?

Comment: could you show example ?

Comment: I could use a service, but see my edit.

Comment: the child controller has access to parent scope. You can declar a method on parent scope to enable/disable the button, and call this method from the child scope.

Comment: @Callebe you are right, sir. I did just that and that is the simplest solution. Got it working in less than 20 seconds. Forgot about `$parent`

Comment: @Ronnie depending on the nature of your application a service could still be the better way to go.  If you introduce another controller then $parent could refer to the wrong parent and you'd have to do $parent.$parent.  This is one of those things of 'right' vs. the business value way to fix it, and that's your decision :)

Comment: I understand, but I won't be adding anymore controllers. If I didn't do it this way, I would have probably just done a broadcast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent controller you can declare a method like this

```
$scope.toggleButton = function () {
    $scope.button_disabled = !$scope.button_disabled;
};
```

And in your child controller you can call this method

```
$scope.toggleButton();
```

the parent view button can be like this

```
<button ng-disabled="button_disabled">Parent Button</button>
```